# OpenCV (Gstreamer Exception): reading videostream from Online Camera

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, webcam

I try to read a webcam stream with OpenCV (address end with :5555/mjpg/101.jpg). I use OpenCV to read the images with:

```
camera_number101 = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5555/mjpg/101.jpg"
cap101 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_number101)
ret101, image_np101 = cap101.read()
```

This is just part of my code, but when I start it, it shows the following Exception:
[OpenCV exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2xE0.png)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my installed packages of gstreamer are the following:
[Installed Gstreamer packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2xE0.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To employ gstreamer as an input for opencv you must write a full pipeline. If your cameta is producing a TCP stream of h264 the pipeline may look such as:

```
cv2.VideoCapture('tcpclientsrc host=<IP> port=<PORT> ! h264parse ! x264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink')
```

But you must figure out the exact format and container that your camera is producing.
For a (probably motion-)JPEG decoder you will need to decode jpeg with `jpegdec`.

Also, your opencv install must be compiled with gstreamer support, and have the right gstreamer plugins installed.